# image over the jquery built webcam screen

Tags: jquery, css, web, webcam

I'm trying to place an image, over the webcam screen on my webpage. I used the jQuery webcam plugin to place the webcam screen on my webpage.

Link to the jQuery plugin: http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/

Now I want to place an image above the screen so that I could make the webcam screen invisible, or place an background over it, so it would look like you are behind a tree.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this; I tried by just placing in image over it, but webcam always comes on top.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution might just be to use jQuery to hide the object...

Assumming it's inside a `<div id="webcam">` you could use:

```
 $('#webcam').hide();
```

and then later use:

```
 $('#webcam').fadeIn(); // or .show();
```

But for an image solution you could try something like this:

```
 <div id="webcam">
    <div id="over_image"></div>
    <object id="webcam-object" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/download/jscam_canvas_only.swf" width="320" height="240"><param name="movie" value="/download/jscam_canvas_only.swf"><param name="WMODE" value="transparent"> <param name="FlashVars" value="mode=callback&amp;quality=85"></object>
 </div>
```

Have the css like this:

```
 #webcam { width: 320px; height: 240px; position: relative; }
 #over_image { width: 320px; height: 240px; 
               position: absolute; z-index: 100; top: 0;
               background-image: url('someimage.jpg');
 }
```

Note that you'll need to include:

`<param name="WMODE" value="transparent">` in the flash object and I'm not sure how that jquery plugin sets up flash so you may have to modify some of the code.

If you don't include this the `z-index` property won't function correctly. (This might be why the background image you were trying didn't work correctly.)